# SharePoint 2007 -Content for this URL is excluded by the server because a no-index attribute

Tags: sharepoint, search, attributes, indexing

Did any of guys run into this error where the search crawler is ignoring an aspx page? I am getting the following warning message for these page: "Content for this URL is excluded by the server because a no-index attribute".

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response Nat. I figured out the issue.

We have two version of the site in question, win auth and forms auth. After some digging around a little bit I found out that one of the user controls was breaking in the win auth version - hence the page as well. It was working fine in forms auth. I forgot to add an appsettings entry in the win auth's web.config. So I am guessing when the crawler went to the page, saw the page was broken - it didnt crawl it and recorded the warning message in the crawl log.

After fixing the user control, the page was crawled as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Check the search visibility of the site using the following settings page.
http://[mywebsiteurl]/_layouts/srchvis.aspx

A value of "Never index any aspx pages on this site" will result in the log message. 
Note: individual lists can also be "turned off" with regards to the search crawl.
http://[mywebsiteurl]/_layouts/advsetng.aspx?List=[list GUID] (or more simply go List Settings -> Advanced Settings